# how to save depth image loss-less to disk

Tags: ros, sensor-msgs, depth-image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I would like to record a scene and save depth image + rgb image of the kinect sensor.
therefore I use cv_bridge and save the images to png format. After that I want to use rgbdslam with my recorded data but it seems that I have a lot of data loss.

The color images are stored as 640×480 8-bit RGB images in PNG format.
The depth maps are stored as 640×480 16-bit monochrome images in PNG format.

But when I convert the images back to sensor_msgs::Image and display them with image_view the depth image looks totally different (much darker) as it looks when I directly display the depth image from the sensor.

Would be great to get your thoughts.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53654/how-to-save-depth-image-loss-less-to-disk/) by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 447 on 2013-01-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming 8UC3 rgb image, and 16UC1 depth image, this is what I use for saving and loading:

```
// save images 
cv::imwrite("rgb.png",   rgb_img);
cv::imwrite("depth.png", depth_img);

// load images
rgb_img = cv::imread("rgb.png");
depth_img = cv::imread("depth.png", -1);
```

I believe the crucial part is the **-1** flag. From the [imread](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread#imread) page:

> flags: <0 Return the loaded image as is (with alpha channel).

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2013-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1